# require_once() or AJAX causing php script to run twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I'm making a step by step form that stores session variables as you follow the steps.

On one step I have a file upload that previews the image and shows an upload button, which when pressed calls a php script that needs to modify a $_SESSION variable, as well as echo the path to the uploaded file.

When I test it in my debugger without `require_once('config.php')`, it works exactly as I anticipate, showing the image and it's filename, however, for some reason when I include the config file, when I iterate through it in my debugger, it appears to run the php script twice, it correctly updates the session variable, but the filename isn't echoed anymore and the data is lost before it reaches the frontend.

I can't tell if the mistake is in the `config.php` file, or in the AJAX call, or maybe somewhere else where I'm missing.

The markup ('step4.php'):

```
<form method="post" action="step5.php">
    <span id="newfile">
        <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="imageupload" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
        <img alt="Preview Loading..." id="imagepreview">
    </span>
    <!-- The submit button is elsewhere before the end of the form, it acts as a next button -->
</form>
```

The javascript function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploadbutton', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Grab upload elements and and file
    var uploadbutton = this;
    var uploader = document.getElementById('imageupload');
    var file = document.getElementById('imageupload').files[0];
    //Hide the upload elements
    uploadbutton.parentNode.removeChild(uploadbutton);
    uploader.parentNode.removeChild(uploader);
    //Make the form and pass it to server
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file); //$_FILES['file']
    $.ajax({
        url: 'uploadfile.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    })
    .done(function(data) {//Data is the relative path to the file
        //Hide the old content
        document.getElementById('newfile').innerHTML = '';
        //Show the new image
        var text = document.createTextNode('Uploaded File: '+data.replace('temp/', '', data));
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        var imgElement = document.createElement("IMG");
        imgElement.setAttribute('src', data);
        document.getElementById('newfile').appendChild(text);
        document.getElementById('newfile').appendChild(br);
        document.getElementById('newfile').appendChild(imgElement);
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("Error uploading the file. Hit refresh and try again.");
    });
});
```

'uploadfile.php': (the one that my debugger shows gets executed twice...)

```
<?php
//require_once('config.php'); //THE PROBLEM?

if($_FILES) {
    //Get the uploaded file information
    $name_of_uploaded_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    //Actually upload the file to the server!
    $upload_folder = 'temp/'; //Make a file named temp
    $path_of_uploaded_file = $upload_folder.$name_of_uploaded_file;
    $tmp_path = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];

    if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_path)) {
        copy($tmp_path,$path_of_uploaded_file);
        $_SESSION['step4filepath'] = $path_of_uploaded_file;
        echo $path_of_uploaded_file;
    }   
}

?>
```

'config.php': the one that screws stuff up when it's included

```
<?php
session_start();

//Initialize session data
if(empty($_SESSION)) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION['step4filepath'])) {
        $_SESSION['step4filepath'] = '';
    }
}

//Update session data
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    if($_SESSION['currentPage'] == 4) {
        //input for step 4, we just want filename if they submit the form
        $_SESSION['step4filepath'] = $_POST['step4filepath'];
    }
    //Enable us to hit the back button!
    header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>
```

Totally lost on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this? Why that line is there on your config file?

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Comment: Seems to work! I set it like that so that you would be able to use the back button in a browser without the occasional `Confirm Form Resubmission` message. I disallowed it when the user is currently on page 4. (You answered so quickly that I'll have to wait a little bit to mark you as the one who answered it.) Thank you!

Comment: Don't add back functionality like this ... Use history.back(), and if you want to do it with PHP then try to add few more conditions there in your code. If button click value is this then only back etc etc.

Comment: What conditions would you suggest? It's non-sensitive information that's being posted.

Comment: I am not sure how you intend to enable/use that as back functionality. 
1. Use this instead on your back/cancel button ... <?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>
2. You can also use window.history.back()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like config.php is replacing the value of $_SESSION['step4filepath'] with $_POST['step4filepath'], rather than leaving it as $path_of_uploaded_file.

**EDIT**

As mentioned elsewhere, header() will be causing a reload. My answer is irrelevant as config.php is called before the var is set.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

Replace

```
$(document).on('click', '#uploadbutton', function(e) {
```

To

```
$(document).off('click').on('click', '#uploadbutton', function(e) {
```

Solution 2: See below sample code

```
$(document).on("click", "#someID", function(e) {
    $(this).attr("disabled","disabled");
    // Disabling the input stops the event from firing multiple times.
    var targetObj = $(this);
    // targetObj can be used within the $.POST function, not $(this)
   var myVariable = "Hello world";
   $.post("/DoSomethingAJAXY.php", { variable1: myVariable },
   function(data, status){
    if (status == "success") {
        // Do something
    }
    $(targetObj).removeAttr("disabled");
    // Re-enable the event input trigger
});
}
```